# Get a percentage in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a project where I need to take a comma delimited file with many columns and pull out the company names, the result of a customer interactions and how many times that happened.
Then I need to calculate the percentage of bad interactions to good interactions
I am using Hadoop and Java.
I have a working Map and Reduce that give me the company name and a count of how many good and bad interactions.

My problem is, I cannot find a way to have Hadoop divide the good and bad to give me a percentage.
Most company’s don’t have any bad interactions.

Here is my Mapp

```
public class TermProjectMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable( 1); 
    private Text word = new Text();

      @Override
      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String[] columb = value.toString().split(",");
            String companyName = columb[5];
            String companyResponseToConsumer = columb[12];
            String lookfor = "closed without relief";

                if (companyResponseToConsumer.toLowerCase().contains(lookfor)) {companyResponseToConsumer="Bad";}
                else {companyResponseToConsumer="Good";}
                //System.out.println(companyResponseToConsumer);
                if (companyName != "" && companyResponseToConsumer != "")
                {
                    word.set (companyName + " " + companyResponseToConsumer);
                    context.write( word, one); 
                }
      }
      }
```

Here is my Reduce

```
public class TermProjectReducer extends Reducer < Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > 
{ 
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable(); 
      @Override
        public void reduce( Text key, Iterable < IntWritable > values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        { 
            int sum = 0; 
            for (IntWritable val : values) 
            { 
                sum += val.get(); 
            } 
            if (sum > 0) 
            {
                result.set( sum); 
                context.write( key, result);
            }
        } 
    }
```

This is an example of what I am getting now.

```
AMERICAN EAGLE MORTGAGE COMPANY,Good,   4
AMERICAN EQUITY MORTGAGE,Good,  26 
AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY,Bad,   250 
AMERICAN EXPRESS COMPANY,Good,  9094 
AMERICAN FEDERAL MORTGAGE CORPORATION,Bad,  1 
AMERICAN FEDERAL MORTGAGE CORPORATION,Good, 3 
AMERICAN FINANCE HOUSE LARIBA,Good, 3 
AMERICAN FINANCIAL MORTGAGE COMPANY,Good,   3
```

Comment: Does it have to be Mapreduce instead of Hive/Spark/Pig?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be MapReduce and Java.

Comment: Okay, your reducer is just doing a wordcount. What attempts have you made to separate the counts of only `Good` & `Bad`?

Comment: For example, if you only made your key `Good`, or `Bad`, rather than adding the company name to the key, you would only have those keys in the reducer.

Comment: I need the good bad percentage per company.  I have tried to split the company from the good/bad in the reducer with split command on the comma.  Then calculate the percentage and have it context write the answer, but I have not been able to make that work.  I keep getting errors with the variable types and the for command can only iterate over an array.

Comment: Then your key from the mapper must be only the company name. That way, your reducer can give you a single company to calculate. Then, you will almost certainly need a different Hadoop Writable to wrap both the good and bad counts into a single value. (for example, ArrayWritable https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html)

Comment: Thank you.  I will spend some time and see if I can make that work.

Comment: Or instead of outputting the strings, good and bad, you can output 1 and - 1 as an IntWritable, respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to aggregate the companies, you need to output just those as the keys so they are combined at the reducer. In other words, you want to have both the good and bad values at the same key rather than separated as you have done now.

I initially thought you could do `[1, 0]` or `[0, 1]`, but outputting just `1` or  `-1` instead of `("GOOD", 1)` and `("BAD", 1)` would be easier to deal with. (And more efficient data transfer for Hadoop)

So, for example,

```
private final static IntWritable ONE = new IntWritable(1); 
private final static IntWritable NEG_ONE = new IntWritable(-1); 

...

    IntWritable status;
    if (companyResponseToConsumer.toLowerCase().contains(lookfor)) {status=NEG_ONE;}
    else {status=ONE;}

    if (!companyName.isEmpty())
    {
        word.set (companyName);
        context.write(companyName, status); 
    }
```

Now, in the reducer, count the values as well as calculate the percent.

```
public class TermProjectReducer extends Reducer < Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable > 
{ 
  private IntWritable result = new IntWritable(); 

  @Override
    public void reduce( Text key, Iterable < IntWritable > values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
    { 
        int total = 0; 
        int good_sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) 
        { 
            good_sum += (val.get() == 1 ? 1 : 0); 
            total += 1
        } 
        if (total > 0) // Prevent division by zero
        {
            double percent = 1.0*good_sum/total;
            // Round it to how every many decimal places, if you want
            result.set(String.valueOf(percent)); // convert the floating number to a string
        } else {
            result.set("0.00"); 
        }
        context.write(key, result); 
    } 
}
```

And I only calculated the good values because in your downstream processing you can do `(1 - good) = bad` yourself.

Also, I suggest using a `DoubleWritable` as the Reducer value instead of `Text`

Comment: Thank You cricket_007 that was it.  It took me a little time to get everything working together, but you got me on the right path!  Thank You!